# Should I separate my redux selectors or specify what I need in the map from 1 selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

For maintainability and performance I want to implement selectors across multiple components (and their properties). I am unsure whether or not I should implement a selector per property or use one generic selector and extract the properties that I need from the return object.

I am using ReactJS with Redux and no other bells or whistles attached

Option A

```
   mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            name: getUserName(state),
            address: getAddress(state)
        }
    }
```

Option B

```
    mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            { name, address }: getUser(state)
        }
    }
```

This is a sample return

```
    getUserName(state) = 'Matthew';
    getAddress(state) = 'Disneyland';

    getUser(state) = { 'name': 'Matthew', 'address':'Disneyland'};
```

Which caters better towards performance?

Comment: "caters better towards performance?" Does that matter? Did you measure a performance issue that needs fixing? To me these are merely code-style choices. Unless you're on a hot-path, worrying about performance is moot. This setup code runs very infrequently. Why worry about the performance of a single line of code that will make an inperceptible difference to app-performance? Worrying about the difference in processor-ticks for a destructure and one function call vs 2 function calls is a waste of time. Works? Will be easy to read in 6 month's time? Move on.

Comment: The application manages multiple users, up to 10,000 components and thus the state will be changing and thus re-rendering frequently. I have seen problems in the past with scalability specifically with redux and I've managed to get around the bulk of these issues (as they were primarily dispatcher related) but I still have concerns about the selectors in regard to the above because I am unsure of the effects that returning the entire object and only pulling out two properties will have.

Comment: Sounds like a very easy thing to test. I suspect the difference between the two will be insignificant. Focus on correctness. If it's sluggish when it's correct, don't guess, measure. Otherwise you will waste hours on problems that don't exist.